# Graph cover question

Tags: graph-theory

Given an undirected connected graph containing k nodes with odd degree (and some more in even degree), I need to show that it's possible to cover the graph's edges with k/2 paths (the paths have no common edges)

I could use some help with this one, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: Prove it by induction on $k$. There is a path $P$ from some odd vertex of $G$ to some other odd vertex. Delete all edges in $P$ to get a new graph $G'$ with the same vertex set as $G$. It’s possible that one or more of the vertices in $P$ has degree $0$ in $G'$; if so, remove any such vertices to get a graph $G''$. Show that $G''$ has $k-2$ odd vertices. $G''$ may not be connected, but each of its components is a connected graph with fewer than $k$ odd vertices, so you can apply your induction hypothesis to each component of $G''$.